# validar existencia antes de insertar (c#)

Tags: c#, mysql

Hola buenas tardes a todos, chicos consulta, necesito que al querer insertar un nuevo registro, antes se valide si cierto campo ya existe en la base de datos, para esto tengo un procedimiento almacenado en mysql, lo pruebo en workbench y me funciona, ahora en C# estoy haciendo un método en el cual le paso el parámetro a buscar, pero me arroja el siguiente error: "NO SE PUEDE CONVERTIR IMPLÍCITAMENTE EL TIPO BOOL EN STRING".

trabajo con modelo en capas, en mi capa datos tengo el método en cuestión:

```
 public string validarExistencia(datosFuncionario funcionario)
    {
        //string respuesta = "";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();

        try
        {
            //CADENA DE CONEXION
            con.ConnectionString = conexion.cadenaConexion;

            //ABRIMOS LA CONEXION
            con.Open();

            //COMANDO PARA EJECUTAR CONSULTA
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;

            //LLAMAMOS A LA CONSULTA O PROCEDIMIENTO ALMACENADO
            cmd.CommandText = "spValidaExistFuncionario";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            //ID AUTOINCREMENTAL
            MySqlParameter parIdFunc = new MySqlParameter();
            parIdFunc.ParameterName = "@rut1";
            parIdFunc.MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.VarChar;
            parIdFunc.Size = 25;
            parIdFunc.Value = funcionario.Rut;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parIdFunc);

            //EJECUCION DEL COMANDO
            int respuesta = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            return respuesta == 0;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //respuesta = ex.Message;
        }

        //CIERRE DE CONEXION
        finally
        {
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
        }

        //RETORNAMOS LA VARIABLE DEL METODO
        //return respuesta;
    }
```

y mi procedimiento almacenado es así:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`administrador`@`%` PROCEDURE `spValidaExistFuncionario`(in rut1 varchar(25))
    BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM funcionario WHERE rut = rut1; 

    END
```

y mi botón guardar:

```
        try
        {
            string respuesta = "";

            //validamos los campos obligatorios
            if (this.txtDocumento.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                mensajeError("Faltan datos por ingresar, favor verificar");
                error.SetError(txtDocumento, "Debe Ingresar Numero de Documento");
            }
            else
            {
                if (this.isNuevo)
                {
                   respuesta = negociosFuncionario.insertar(
                   this.txtDocumento.Text,
                   this.txtNombres.Text,
                   this.txtApePat.Text,
                   this.txtApeMat.Text,
                   this.dtpFechaNac.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"),
                   this.cmbSexo.Text,
                   this.txtDireccion.Text,
                   Convert.ToInt32(this.txtFono.Text),
                   this.txtCorreo.Text,
                   this.cmbPrevSalud.Text,
                   this.cmbPrevSocial.Text,
                   this.txtComentarios.Text
                  );
                }
                else
                {
                   respuesta = negociosFuncionario.editar(
                   Convert.ToInt32(this.txtCodFuncionario.Text),
                   this.txtDocumento.Text,
                   this.txtNombres.Text,
                   this.txtApePat.Text,
                   this.txtApeMat.Text,
                   this.dtpFechaNac.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"),
                   this.cmbSexo.Text,
                   this.txtDireccion.Text,
                   Convert.ToInt32(this.txtFono.Text),
                   this.txtCorreo.Text,
                   this.cmbPrevSalud.Text,
                   this.cmbPrevSocial.Text,
                   this.txtComentarios.Text
                  );

                }

                if (respuesta.Equals("OK"))
                {
                    if (this.isNuevo)
                    {
                        this.mensajeOK("REGISTRO INSERTADO CON EXITO EN LA BASE DE DATOS");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.mensajeOK("REGISTRO ACTUALIZADO CON EXITO");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    this.mensajeError(respuesta);
                }

                this.isNuevo = false;
                this.isEditar = false;
                this.botones();
                this.limpiarControles();
                this.cargarGrilla();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

Saludos a todos, que tengan una gran jornada.

Comment: Deja que tanto la comparación como la inserción las haga el procedimiento almacenado, o bien utiliza [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa937723(v=vs.113).aspx). Con cualquiera de las dos opciones reduces el riesgo de dejar inconsistencias en tu base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cambia la siguiente línea de código:

```
 return respuesta == 0;
```

Por:

```
return respuesta.ToString();
```

**Explicación:**

Tu función está definida para retornar un dato de tipo **string**:

```
public string validarExistencia(datosFuncionario funcionario)
{
```

Tu variable resultado es de tipo Int, sin embargo la línea de código siguiente es una comparación por lo tanto retorna un tipo bool:

```
  return respuesta == 0;
```

Usa el método ToString() para convertirla al mismo tipo de datos. También pudieras cambiar el tipo de datos de tu función a int si así te conveniese.

**Nota:**

Si con la instrucción antes mencionada deseas retornar el valor cero en el caso de que el resultado sea nulo puedes usar el siguiente código:

```
        object obj = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        int respuesta = ((obj==DBNull.Value)? 0: Convert.ToInt32(obj));
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda alejando, entendí lo de la función, ahora te hago otra consulta, como haría para usar esa función en mi botón (edite la pregunta incluyendo el código que tengo del botón), la idea es que si el sp me arroja cero, no hay registro y pase al método insertar, caso contrario pase al actualizar

Comment: @NicolasEzequielAlmonacid creo que esto ya te lo comente en otro lado. Pero no debes editar la pregunta y añadir una nueva despues de contestada, porque si es asi invalidas la respuesta. Si tenes otra pregunta nueva, hacela.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido @NicolasEzequielAlmonacid, estoy de acuerdo con gbianchi abre una nueva pregunta con lo del botón y te ayudo con gusto

Comment: perfecto @AlejandroMedina, abri un nuevo tema con esta misma consulta, pero incluyendo codigo fuente...

Comment: @NicolasEzequielAlmonacid Si te sirvió la respuesta no olvides marcala, saludos